# Sorting array with multiple different fields - doesn't sort by char

Tags: c#, arrays, sorting

Here's my class:

```
public class walidacja
{
    public char znak { get; set; }
    public double wyj_neuron_1 { get; set; }
    public double wyj_neuron_2 { get; set; }
    public double wyj_neuron_3 { get; set; }
    public double wyj_neuron_1_norm { get; set; }
    public double wyj_neuron_2_norm { get; set; }
    public double wyj_neuron_3_norm { get; set; }
    public bool rozpoznaj { get; set; }

    public walidacja(char lit, double a, double b, double c, bool test)
    {
        this.znak = lit;
        this.wyj_neuron_1 = a;
        this.wyj_neuron_2 = b;
        this.wyj_neuron_3 = c;
        this.wyj_neuron_1_norm = a / (a + b + c);
        this.wyj_neuron_2_norm = b / (a + b + c);
        this.wyj_neuron_3_norm = c / (a + b + c);
        this.rozpoznaj = test;
    }
}
```

Then I declare

```
valid = new walidacja[counter];
```

I fill the array with data. Znak gets filled with equal number of 3 letters (so if counter = 15, there will be 5 a's, 5 b's, 5 c's in the znak field).

Why does this not sort the array by char znak?

```
valid.OrderBy(a => a.znak);
```

Comment: Sort/OrderBy doesnt act on the object - it returns a new `valid` ordered

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`OrderBy` returns a new sequence, it doesn't change your array. You need to assign it back:

```
valid = valid.OrderBy(a => a.znak).ToArray();
```